SQL to sum duration of status timestamps at hourly intervals, accounting for statuses that span hours
I've been smashing my head at solving a problem that I can validate in Excel but just a few minutes off in SQL. The scenario is a table with three columns below, where I am trying to get each user and their respective duration of statuses at hourly intervals.
Each row represents when a user has entered a status, where the next row represents a change to a new status. The duration of the current row status is therefore the LEAD - current row timestamps. That works great in aggregate (SUM is the correct time), but when grouped by hour the timestamps are not accurate to the proportion of the current and next hour interval for a given status that spans both.
| Timestamp        | Status    | Duration |
| ---------------- | --------- | -------- |
| 5/15/24 18:26:56 | AVAILABLE | 0:00:30  |
| 5/15/24 18:27:26 | AVAILABLE | 0:14:07  |
| 5/15/24 18:41:33 | AVAILABLE | 0:02:01  |
| 5/15/24 18:43:34 | AVAILABLE | 0:24:21  |
| 5/15/24 19:07:55 | AVAILABLE | 0:07:11  |
| 5/15/24 19:15:06 | AVAILABLE | 0:10:00  |
| 5/15/24 19:25:06 | AVAILABLE | 0:18:15  |
| 5/15/24 19:43:21 | TRAINING  | 0:00:00  |
| 5/15/24 19:43:21 | TRAINING  | 0:04:13  |
| 5/15/24 19:47:34 | AVAILABLE | 0:00:00  |
| 5/15/24 19:47:34 | AVAILABLE | 0:02:10  |
| 5/15/24 19:49:44 | AVAILABLE | 0:13:09  |
| 5/15/24 20:02:53 | AVAILABLE | 0:11:02  |

The duration for the 1800 hour should be 00:33:04, which represents 18:26:56 to 18:59:59. The duration for the 1900 hour should be 1:00:00, which represents 19:00:00 to 19:59:59. I've confirmed this via Excel. However, in SQL I get 00:33:04 for the 1800 hour (correct) and 00:52:05 for the 1900 hour (incorrect). The 07:55 difference represents the time from 19:00:00 to 19:07:55, which is the first timestamp of the hour I am not calculating correctly.
Below is the query I have so far, which leaves me a few minutes short each hour.
WITH StatusChanges AS (
  SELECT 
    USER_ID, STATUS, TIMESTAMP AS currentTimestamp,
    //Find the timestamp in the row BEFORE and puts it into an adjacent column
    LAG(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS previousTimestamp, 
    //Find the timestamp in the row AFTER and puts it into an adjacent column
    LEAD(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS nextTimestamp 
  FROM TABLENAME
  WHERE USER_ID IN ('ABCD1234')
),
StatusIntervals AS (
  SELECT
    USER_ID, STATUS, currentTimestamp, previousTimestamp, nextTimestamp, DATE_PART(HOUR, currentTimestamp) AS hour_of_day,
    CASE
      //Handle the last timestamp of the day
      WHEN nextTimestamp IS NULL THEN 0
      //When the timestamp now and next are in the same hour
      WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM nextTimestamp) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM currentTimestamp) THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,currentTimestamp, nextTimestamp) 
      //When the timestamp next in in the next hour, cut off duration at the top of the next hour
      WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM nextTimestamp) > EXTRACT(HOUR FROM currentTimestamp) THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,currentTimestamp, DATE_TRUNC(HOUR,nextTimestamp)) of the hour
      //When the timestamp is the first within the hour interval (pretty sure this is wrong)
      ELSE THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,DATE_TRUNC(HOUR,previousTimestamp),currentTimestamp) 
    END AS durationToUse, 
  FROM StatusChanges
)
SELECT
    hour_of_day,
    USER_ID,
    STATUS,
    TO_TIME(TO_VARCHAR(ROUND(SUM(durationToUse),0))) AS durationApproach1
FROM StatusIntervals
GROUP BY
    hour_of_day,
    USER_ID,
    STATUS
ORDER BY
    dayOfWeekET ASC,
    hour_of_day ASC,
    USER_ID ASC,
    durationApproach1 DESC


You can show desired result as table? And what DBMS?
